# Catching a nested-in-template exception [C++]

Tags: c++, exception, templates

I have a problem with writing a catch clause for an exception that is a class nested in a template. To be more specific, I have a following definition of the template and exception:

```
/** Generic stack implementation.
    Accepts std::list, std::deque and std::vector
    as inner container. */
template <
typename T,
    template <
        typename Element,
        typename = std::allocator<Element>
    > class Container = std::deque
>
class stack {  
public:
    class StackEmptyException { };
    ...

    /** Returns value from the top of the stack.
        Throws StackEmptyException when the stack is empty. */
    T top() const;
   ...
}
```

I have a following template method that I want exception to catch:

```
template <typename Stack>
void testTopThrowsStackEmptyExceptionOnEmptyStack() {
    Stack stack;
    std::cout << "Testing top throws StackEmptyException on empty stack...";

    try {
        stack.top();
    } catch (Stack::StackEmptyException) {
        // as expected.
    }

    std::cout << "success." << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile it (-Wall, -pedantic) I get the following error:

```
In function ‘void testTopThrowsStackEmptyExceptionOnEmptyStack()’:
error: expected type-specifier
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

What is interesting, if the stack implementation was not a template, then the compiler would accept the code as it is.

PS. I also tried redefining the template method type, but I couldn't make this work.

Comment: @Karol, since you are new in SO land: If you found your problem is solved, you should pick an answer as "accepted" (click on the mark left to the answer). So people can see that your problem is already solved by an answer.

Comment: By the way, do you actually need each different kind of stack to throw a different class of exception? `stack<int>::StackEmptyException` and `stack<float>::StackEmptyException` are unrelated types. What if you wanted to catch it higher up in the code, somewhere that knows that there is a stack in use but does not know (or need to know) which one?

Comment: I agree with Steve, I usually don't create new exceptions as nested classes within a template class. I prefer to create a base class (like `BaseStack`) to define my exceptions and have each template class `Stack<T>` inheriting from `BaseStack`, this way I have the possibility of catching those exceptions outside the template code without enumerating all the possible template specializations.

Comment: I'd probably just put the exception in the same namespace as the `stack` class template. Saves any confusion what the base class is supposed to be for (not polymorphism, not code-re-use, just somewhere to put the exceptions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `typename`:

```
template <typename Stack>
void testTopThrowsStackEmptyExceptionOnEmptyStack() {
    Stack stack;
    std::cout << "Testing top throws StackEmptyException on empty stack...";

    try {
        stack.top();
    } catch (typename Stack::StackEmptyException) {
        // as expected.
    }

    std::cout << "success." << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler's parser otherwise assumes that `Stack::StackEmptyException` is not a type and misparses the code (it can't *know* that it is a type, because at that point it doesn't know what type `Stack` is, so potentially `StackEmptyException` could be a static data-member likewise). You should also generally catch by reference instead of by value.

Comment: See the templates faq too: http://womble.decadentplace.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html